# Disable logging Trace id, Span Id for few endpoints in Spring Sleuth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Spring Sleuth for distributed tracing. In my logs, I am able to see Span Id, Trace Id like below

```
  2020-05-22 11:07:43.388  INFO  [Project,fff1bc87aebe740a,fff1bc87aebe740a,false] - request received for url /info
```

But I want to disable logging Trace Id, Span Id for some URLs, For URL /info my logs should look like

```
  2020-05-22 11:07:43.388  INFO  [Project] - request received for url /info
```

Is it possible to achieve this? I found spring.sleuth.web.additionalSkipPattern = /info, but this still logs the id's in my logs.

Comment: I think you can only disable an entire service.